# sml list [tycon mismatch] operand and operator don't agree

Tags: list, sml

I'm trying to loop through a datatype, SET, that contains other datatypes including itself, and printing out those datatypes using a looping function, loop.

```
fun printEXP(SET(hd::tl::[])) =
    let    
    fun loop (hd::tl) = printEXP(hd):: loop tl | loop [] = []; 
    in () end;
 ...
```

I'm getting a tycon mismatch error and I'm not sure how to fix it. What am I doing wrong in my loop function?

```
operator domain: EXP list
operand: EXP
```

where

```
datatype EXP = SET of EXP list;
```

Comment: Your error is on line 3, more specifically `printEXP(hd)`. This is because `hd` is of type EXP and your function takes an `EXP list`.

Answer (score 2):

This pattern:

```
SET(hd::tl::[])
```

means a `SET ___` where the argument is a list with exactly two elements, `hd` and `tl`. (It's equivalent to `SET [hd, tl]`.)

Instead, you meant to write:

```
SET(hd::tl)
```

meaning a `SET ___` where the argument is a list with at least one element, `hd`; `tl` is then the list of all elements after `hd` (if any).

But what you should *really* write is:

```
SET xs
```

meaning a `SET ___` where the argument is any list at all, called `xs`. You don't need to deconstruct `xs` at this point; rather, your inner `loop` function handles the deconstruction, and (more importantly) also handles the case that the list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your function is that `printEXP` takes an `EXP list` argument, whereas your `hd` supplies an `EXP` type.

To get around this, you must probably have other things in your `EXP` type. Therefore, you should - in your print function - explore the other types.

Secondly, your function would throw a non-exhaustive or match-redundant error, because your only checking if the list contains a head and tail. Take a look at the example supplied.

For example:

```
datatype EXP = INT of int | SET of EXP list;

fun printEXP (INT i) = print (Int.toString i)
  | printEXP (SET (hd::tl)) = do main set things
  | printEXP (SET []) = do empty set things
```

Hope this helps

Comment: -1, sorry. This function takes an `EXP` argument. (Note that `SET` is a constructor of type `EXP list -> EXP`.) The problem is actually with the `loop tl`, because `tl` is of type `EXP` (rather than of type `EXP list` as intended).

Comment: @ruakh but the problem starts with the `hd`, yes `tl` also produces the problem, that's where I suggested the function to properly go through the `EXP list` in my answer.

Comment: I don't see why you think there's a problem with the `hd`. The OP's error message shows exactly the opposite of what you describe.